# Heroku app crashes when in a docker container

Tags: docker, heroku

I have the following heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.application
```

And I'm pushing to heroku, and the Docker container loads correctly and the app is deployed too without any warnings or errors, but the app crashes, with these logs:

```
2020-04-07T22:58:22.151943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-07T22:58:22.157295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-07T22:58:22.098498+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: java: not found
2020-04-07T22:58:25.714638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-07T22:58:25.654321+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: java: not found
```

Why is java not found and what am I doing wrong?

---EDIT---

This is the docker file

```
# We will use Ubuntu for our image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Updating Ubuntu packages

ARG CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION=1.10.1.507


RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install curl wget bzip2 openjdk-8-jdk-headless \
    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp /usr/local \
    && rm -rf /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update conda \
    && curl -o install-clojure https://download.clojure.org/install/linux-install-${CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION}.sh \
    && chmod +x install-clojure \
    && ./install-clojure && rm install-clojure \
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein \
    && chmod a+x lein \
    && mv lein /usr/bin \
    && apt-get -qq -y autoremove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/log/dpkg.log \
    && conda clean --all --yes


ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN conda create -n pyclj python=3.6 && conda install -n pyclj numpy mxnet

## To install pip packages into the pyclj environment do
RUN conda run -n pyclj python3 -mpip install numpy
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: It's in the edit

Comment: can you try to build that image locally with `docker build -t test .` later run `docker run -ti test bash` and run `java` command to see if it is correctly installed ?

Comment: you mean on this step `docker build -t test .` if it hangs can be related to your docker local setup

Comment: Yes, java is there when I do docker build -t test ., docker run -ti test bash and java. So the same docker file enables java locally but not on Heroku. Why would that be?

Comment: so seems like it uses `shell` on heroku I guess you can do same test as before but now `docker run -ti test /bin/sh` and see if `java` is configured on PATH, that's the only think I can think that can be

Comment: Also, last thing to check can be related to some kind of error on the herolu.yml, I mean maybe the command has a special char

Comment: java runs after doing docker run -ti test /bin/sh too

Comment: I've checked using https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector that there are no special characters

Comment: Mmm last thing, can you add that command as an entry point on the last line of dockerfile. And build image locally and try to run it? If it works deploy it without the command

Comment: Adding RUN java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/vendo.jar clojure.main -m vendo.application as the last line in the Dockerfile gives:
Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.main.

So for some reason clojure.main is found when running through the Dockerfile but is when running thought heroku.yml?

The command '/bin/sh -c java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/vendo.jar clojure.main -m vendo.application' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: change it to `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "$JVM_OPTS", "-cp", "target/myapp.jar", "clojure.main" ,"-m" ,"myapp.application"]` and build that image with `docker build -t test .` after that just run it like this `docker run -ti test` and let me know how it goes

Comment: That gives Error: Could not find or load main class $JVM_OPTS when trying to run it.

Comment: It isn't found running through the heroku.yml either. Now the error isn't that java isn't found but that clojure.main isn't found

Comment: yeah you are right just replace with jvm opts since that env var is not defined on the Dockerfile

Comment: Replace $JVM_OPTS with what?

Comment: with the JVM_OPTS you need to use or just remove it if you are not sueç